# SQL LIKE % FOR INTEGERS

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

In T-SQL, how do I write the query to select rows for any integer value for a column??

For example, the data is like this

```
NAME,AGE
A,10
B,20
C,10
D,20
```

and There's a `<asp:dropdownlist>` that has two options, `10,20`, so that a user can select either `10` or `20`. If the user selects `10` or `20`, The data is being pulled correctly, but how do I say a `*` condition?? - like select ALL data for ANY value in the `age` column??

My code is as follows,

`select ...where (AGE = @AGE)`

`<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="AGE" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
        DbType="Int32" DefaultValue="ANY"`

Also, the follow query works perfectly in the SSMS, but how to implement this behavior in asp.net SqlDataSource??

`SELECT * FROM [TABLE] where AGE is not null`

If the column AGE was of varchar type, I am able to use the '%', but it's an numeric field

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you just skip the WHERE clause? If you want to select any age, I don't understand why you would add a condition about it.

Comment: I want to have it in the WHERE clause because the data needs to be pulled if a user selects a value from the dropdown. Removing it from from the WHERE would effectively make the dropdown useless..

Comment: @user331225 no, you add "ANY" as the first (or last) option in the dropdown box. Then your code checks whether the user selected that "ANY" field. If he did, you don't add a where age=@age to your SQL. If the user selected any of the other choices, you do add the where clause.

Comment: Are you trying to use one SQL query for all cases no matter what the user selects?

Answer (score 4):

To provide an ALL/ANY option, you need to specify a sentinel value -- a value that will never exist in your dataset -- so you can check the variable submitted to the stored procedure in order to know when to ignore the variable and use the correct WHERE clause.

IE: If the drop down list has an element with the display text of "All", and a value of -1, the following dynamic SQL would be appropriate:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

   SET @SQL = N'SELECT * 
                  FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
                 WHERE 1 = 1 '

   SET @SQL = @SQL + CASE 
                       WHEN @age > 0 THEN 
                         ' AND age = @age '
                       ELSE 
                         ' AND age IS NOT NULL '
                     END

BEGIN

  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL N'age INT', @age

END
```

See [this link for more details about dynamic SQL in TSQL/SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

But you don't have to use dynamic SQL - this is equivalent:

```
IF @age > 0 
BEGIN

   SELECT * 
     FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
    WHERE age IS NOT NULL

END
ELSE
BEGIN

   SELECT * 
     FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
    WHERE age = @age

END
```

...just that you can imagine how unwieldy this gets if you have multiple parameters that are independent of one another.

Comment: You're thinking too hard.  Many "AND (@age = age OR @age < 0)" clauses wouldn't get unwieldy. :)

Comment: @mootinator: No, because what you provided is non-sargable.  I'm very much aware of the approach -- I've had to remove it in numerous occaissions because it performs horribly.

Comment: Hmm, have you explained this somewhere?  I'm interested.  I inherited a code base full of these types of conditions and some of them do seem to perform inexplicably badly.

Comment: @mootinator: How big were your tables?  And how many parameters?  The ones I remember were upwards of ten parameters, against tables that would have 100K+ rows...

Comment: What I don't understand is why 1=1 is ok but @age = 1 is baaad.

Comment: @mootinator: `1 = 1` is ignored by the optimizer; the issue is the OR in brackets -- *that* is what is non-sargable.

Comment: Upwards of ten parameters, against tables that would have 100K+ rows describes them perfectly.

Comment: @mootinator: That's... convenient.  If you have a question to ask--use proper channels, not hijacking via comments.

Comment: I don't have a question to ask at the moment, I'm just wishing there were some sort of tip feature for when someone gives you something to think about. :)

Answer (score 3):

The standard answer to this using just declarative data sources is to use an OR clause in the SQL Statement

```
WHERE (age = @age OR @age = -1)
```

For certain column types, you'll want to compare to NULL, but you've already stated that -1 was your sentinel value for this column in this application.  Keep an eye on performance with this, eventually you may want to switch to dynamic sql, but this technique works fine with most moderately sized data sets.

Answer (score 2):

See if this works for you. **Turn "ANY" into a NULL and use COALESCE to match against AGE.**

If "param" is "ANY", then we turn it into NULL and then return "age", so that everything matches.  If "param" is anything else, only rows with matching ages will be returned.

```
CREATE TABLE #table (
  age int
)
GO

INSERT INTO #table VALUES (10)
INSERT INTO #table VALUES (20)
INSERT INTO #table VALUES (30)
GO

DECLARE @param varchar(10)
SET @param = 10
SELECT * FROM #table WHERE age = @param

SET @param = 'ANY'
SELECT * FROM #table WHERE age = COALESCE(NULLIF(@param,'ANY'),age)
```

**Results**

```
age
-----------
10

(1 row(s) affected)

age
-----------
10
20
30

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Why not just let @param be NULL?  `age = age` won't work if there needs to be a NULL comparison

Comment: Assumption on my part.  The original query excluded NULLs, so I assume that no NULL will be queried.  "ANY" was chosen because it was the DefaultValue in DropDownList1, which is used to select the age to display.  The OP can provide more details if this solution will not work for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Do not include it in the where

Comment: I want to have it in the WHERE clause because the data needs to be pulled if a user selects a value from the dropdown. Removing it from from the WHERE would effectively make the dropdown useless..

Answer (score 1):

A typical practice is to start with a base query which returns all results:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE 1=1";
```

Then if you have an optional parameter selected, add to the string.

```
sql += " AND AGE = @age";
```

1=1 always evaluates to true, so it's there to eliminate the decision as to whether you need to put an AND or not before your optional condition.

To do this in a SqlDataSource you'll probably mix my and OMG Ponies approach:

```
datasource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE 1=1 AND (AGE = @age OR @age = -1)";
```

Comment: hmm... but still the " AND AGE=@age " evaluates to some value of age, but not for ALL values in age.. For example, if @age=x, then the sql effectively becomes `...AND AGE=x`, but I want to satisfy a case where AGE is x or y or z - all values of AGE.

Comment: I just updated, use OR with a sentinel value for when you want no filter.

Comment: You'll want brackets around the OR

Comment: no.. it doesn't work either. because of `WHERE 1=1 OR AGE=@age`, the values of `@age` will be ignored completely - it basically will have no effect on the query processing.

Comment: I wrote `AND age = @age` actually.  That's entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

You should add it as an optional select clause, example...

```
SELECT *
FROM <Table>
WHERE (@Age is Null OR @Age = '' OR @Age = Age)
```

Now if you return a null or blank value for age, it will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one query where you can pass in one parameter and work with both conditions then you use something like

```
Select Name, Age from 
(
      SELECT 
       (CASE 
        WHEN @p1 = '*' THEN '*'   
        ELSE    CONVERT(NVarChar,Age)
        END) AS SearchCriteria, 
        Name, 
        Age
    FROM table
 ) 
 t
 where SearchCriteria = @p1
```

Parameter must be a NVarchar, but can be '*' or '10' or '20'

Warning. Performance will not be great (Ok, it will be terrible if the table has a lot of rows). It might be better if you used a value of 0 if you want all ages which would remove the need to convert everything to strings.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use one SQL query for all cases no matter what the user selects?
 It would be much easier to use two different queries depending on user selection. When the user selects "ANY"

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE @Age > 0
```

This would match all ages.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question, or at least to the title of the question 'SQL LIKE % FOR INTEGERS', just because there will be others coming to this page because of the title - just like me.

Given you have table 'Ages'

```
NAME,AGE
A,10
B,20
C,10
D,20
E,11
```

and you want all with age 10-19, or round ages (*0) you will need a LIKE % FOR INTEGERS
here is how this can be done with a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT CAST(AGE AS VARCHAR) as Age FROM Ages) tmp where Age like '1%'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT CAST(AGE AS VARCHAR) as Age FROM Ages) tmp where Age like '%0'
```

Have Fun