# Select Row Based on Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with data like the following:

```
ID    Mfgr    Primary_Mfgr
a1    Acme    P
a1    Bcme    S
a1    Ccme    S
b1    Acme
b1    Bcme
c1    Acme    S
c1    Bcme
d1    Acme
d1    Bcme
```

I need to create a select statement that will, based on ID return the record with a P as the Primary_Mfgr, if there is no P record, then return the blank record, if those don't exist then return the first S record. In all cases, if there are duplicates return the first result.

Therefore, using the above data I would expect to return the following from four different queries:

Query for a1:

```
a1    Acme    P
```

Query for b1:

```
b1    Acme
```

Query for c1:

```
c1    Bcme
```

Query for d1:

```
d1    Acme
```

In every case I need to return just one record. I'm not sure how I would structure to do this. I can easily get back all the 'a1' records for example, but I'm not sure how I would write a query that can take a parameter for ID and still return the correct single record in all circumstances. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: You need to define "first". SQL has no sense of ordering within a table. Your query defines ordering.

Comment: This reminds me of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485965/t-sql-conditional-where-clause

Comment: I don't particularly care which order they come back in. If there are two the a 'S' just give me the one that comes back from the server first. If there are duplicate types the order becomes unimportant for my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just order by the Primary_Mfgr column with a case statement and then select the top 1

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Table1
WHERE ID = @ID
ORDER BY 
    CASE Primary_Mfgr 
        WHEN 'P' THEN 1
        WHEN ''  THEN 2
        ELSE 3
    END
```

Comment: this will only return one row. Not "one row per ID group"

Comment: He says "In every case I need to return just one record".  And he mentions 4 different queries.

Comment: The output would suggest that OP want "one row per group" but doesn't know how. If there are 1.2 million IDs do you suggest 1.2 million queries? Your WHERE is wrong too -1

Comment: Awesome; that worked great. Thanks for the quick response. The only thing I changed was the where clause to filter by ID instead of Primary_Mfgr.

Comment: Yeah, I messed up the ID.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Ok, gbn, I didn't interpret his request the same way.  Perhaps you're right.

Comment: I've changed to +1: I looked at it and saw "do it in one set based query"... your simpler solution is what OP wants after all. Although, see the comment to my answer.

Comment: My database is on one partition, so I'm not familiar with some of the code.  That is an intriguing way to do this.

Comment: The syntax 'PARTITION BY' has nothing to do with your database being on one or many partitions. The 'PARTITION BY' syntax is extremely useful for many things. You might want to give that a Google.

Comment: Interesting note: I was testing this solution and didn't limit by ID on accident and my result set didn't come back properly. This worked great and very fast, but for anything over a single ID gbn's answer is the way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

This takes the "first" Mfgr alphabetically (subject to collation etc) where there is more than one for given ID/Primary_Mfgr pair. Otherwise you can change the secondary sort to another column (of you have one) or leave it out to get a random record.

```
;WITH myCTE AS
(
    SELECT
       *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
               PARTITION BY ID
               ORDER BY
                  CASE Primary_Mfgr 
                     WHEN 'P' THEN 1 WHEN 'S' THEN 3 ELSE 2
                  END, Mfgr) AS rn
    FROM
       MyTable
)
SELECT *
FROM myCTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Edit: you don't have to query once per ID which is silly: this answer does it for all IDs in one go. So your 4 queries above become one.

Comment: I didn't select this answer because it requires a lot of extra work for the server when in every case I'll know the ID before I execute the query, so it doesn't seem that partitioning by ID makes sense when there is only one ID returned. However, I can see how this might be useful for other cases, so thanks for sharing.

Comment: I actually do need to return only one row per request due to some other factors which I haven't included here. I'm actually working to get that requirement changed and if that happens I'll use your answer, but right now only one row at a time can come back.